# What does this particular logogram from "Arrival" mean?

Tags: translation, arrival

Closely related to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/151672/are-there-any-tools-or-code-for-analyzing-arrival-logograms), but I couldn't find the answer to my particular question there.

I am interested in meaning of the following logogram which has appeared in the movie "Arrival":

[image: Logogram from Arrival]
[image: Logogram in film still]

In the second image, we see a scene from the actual movie and next to it we see recognized "partial meanings" of the logogram, but I am curious what is its exact meaning.

For the record, I am interested in this particular logogram since it appears on [a T-shirt](https://www.teepublic.com/t-shirt/719343-arrival-movie), and I want what it says before I get the shirt.

Comment: Well, isn't the meaning a combination of elements? Seems more or less clear.

Comment: “This would look boss on your lower back”

Answer (score 5):

The Wolfram people have also published all the logograms along with the code they used, on [GitHub](https://github.com/WolframResearch/Arrival-Movie-Live-Coding/tree/master/ScriptLogoJpegs) (you can download the source code as an archive along with images). Each .jpg file is signed, so I assume the signature is the meaning.

[image: Ink logogram from the "Arrival" film]

This particular diagram is named `HepWritesRealTime1.jpg` - I haven't the slightest idea what that means.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I'm afraid this doesn't exactly answer the question though.

Comment: @Wojowu I'm aware of this as well, so I'm still digging. Sadly, of miriads of websites discussing this stuff, only precious few actually provide something original or relevant - others just re-post. That Wolfram code is the best thing we've got. I also checked the stream, and Christopher Wolfram doesn't explain the logogram there either.

Answer (score 1):

Per my answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/269373/20774), around 30 of the logogram vocabulary words that were generated for the film have been revealed in [*The Art and Science of Arrival*](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/59205215) and on the [WolframResearch Github repository](https://github.com/WolframResearch/Arrival-Movie-Live-Coding/tree/master/ScriptLogoJpegs).

Based on this, we can identify a couple of specific elements of the logogram 'sentence' you've pictured above.

[image]

Comment: Does the bump on the bottom left of "See Find Understand Think Query Ask Truth Land Perch Ground Hold Choose Pick Take Accept" look like the bottom bump on "Ship Grounded" to you too?

Comment: @Malady - It does indeed. But which bit is ship and which bit is grounded?

Comment: Betting that "Ground(ed)" is related to the bump that appears on both these logograms of concern, at least? ... "Heptopod" and "Ship Grounded" seem to share the "Heptopod" segment, so "Ship" might not be the best translation, more "Heptopod Spacecraft" or something.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the "Partial Meanings" are actually fully accurate, because it's easier for the writing / programming that way.

Whether it means anything: "See Find Understand Think Query Ask Truth Land Perch Ground Hold Choose Pick Take Accept"

Seems like there's three concept segments: "See Find Understand Think Query Ask Truth", "Land Perch Ground", and "Hold Choose Pick Take Accept".

And the order presented isn't always the most understandable one. Language without beginning or end. "Accept Ground Truth" is a funny possible meaning.

If we take the implied subject of the speaker talking, then it's maybe [We] Accept [You] Ask [about] Landing.

Especially, from Valorum's answers, this logogram looks sorta like the Ship Grounded logogram, with the small bump looking like a match, at least, and "Land Ground Perch" are more verbs than nouns for locations.

Comment: Land Perch and Ground may also tie semantically to the first group, something along the lines of foundational ground truth from which to proceed in understanding. That is "Land Perch Ground" may *not* be about where to park the spaceship.